# Obtener un mapa personalizado por partes

Tags: google-static-maps, google-geocoding-api

Necesito obtener una cuadrícula de imágenes desde Google Maps (API de mapas estáticos) con ciertas características, que serían:

- Ninguna etiqueta o cartel.
- Todos los edificios de color negro (`0x000000`).
- Todos los caminos, carreteras, autopistas, ..., de color blanco (`0xffffff`).
- Todos los parques, bosques o zonas no urbanizadas, de color verde (`0x00ff00`).
- Todos los ríos, lagos o zonas con agua de color azul (`0x0000ff`).

Solicitando un mapa estático sin configurar nada, obtenemos una imagen como esta:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Barcelona&size=400x400&zoom=18
```

[image]

Así que he añadido ciertas configuraciones:

- `style=element:labels|visibility:off` para eliminar etiquetas y carteles.
- `style=feature:road|color:0xffffff` para mostrar los caminos en blanco.
- `style=feature:landscape|color:0x000000` para mostrar los edificios en negro.
- `style=feature:poi.park|color:0x00ff00` para mostrar parques en verde.
- `style=feature:water|color:0x0000ff` para mostrar zonas de agua en azul.

Con esta configuración el resultado ha cambiado a:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Barcelona&size=400x400&zoom=18&size=400x400&style=element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:road|color:0xffffff&style=feature:landscape|color:0x000000&style=feature:poi.park|color:0x00ff00&style=feature:water|color:0x0000ff
```

[image]

#### Problemas de render.

Casi he obtenido lo que necesito, salvo por los siguientes problemas:

- Los edificios siguen mostrando su modelo 3D y superponiendo su proyección sobre los caminos y carreteras, falseando su trazado pues quedan parcialmente ocultos (en el ejemplo se puede ver un camino cortado en el centro izquierda).
- Hay edificios que no se muestran en negro (en el ejemplo se puede ver uno en la parte central superior).

Me gustaría poder desactivar los edificios 3D del render del mapa y/o renderizarlos en otro color (por ejemplo rojo `0xff0000`) además de incluir en el render todos los edificios (al parecer `landscape` no es la categoría para todos los edificios).

#### Problemas de coordenadas.

Obtengo las coordenadas de una localización mediante la API de Google Geocoding, mediante las coordenadas obtenidas voy extrayendo *recortes* de una localización determinada que puestos unos junto a otros dan lugar a el mapa completo de la localización (por ejemplo, para México DC me devuelve latitud `19.5927571` longitud `-98.9604482` como coordenada superior izquierda y latitud `19.1887101` longitud `-99.3267771` como coordenada inferior derecha) mediante ensayo y error he podido comprobar que desplazando la longitud múltiplos de `0.0043` con zoom 17 cada uno de los recortes encaja horizontalmente pero (siguiendo en México) debo aumentar la latitud `0.0041` para tener el mismo efecto.

Además, se me descuadran los recortes a medida que me alejo verticalmente. Esto seguramente se deba a que los meridianos son cada vez más estrechos a medida que nos desplazamos hacia Norte o Sur:

[image]

[[He creado un Fiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/xjoch4av/) que muestra este efecto, está preparado para funcionar "*casi bien*" en México DC, pero cualquier otra coordenada muestra descuadres mayores. En el Fiddle de ejemplo se ve cómo la segunda fila de imágenes obtiene descuadres respecto a la fila anterior a medida que nos desplazamos a la derecha.

#### Preguntas.

- ¿Cómo puedo forzar que todos los edificios se muestren en el mismo color?
- ¿Cómo debo desactivar el render de los ediificios 3D en niveles altos de zoom?
- ¿De qué manera puedo solventar el problema de los descuadres de recortes de mapas al desplazarme por coordenadas?

Comment: tu fiddle no funciona

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me ha funcionado. ¿qué problema te ha dado?

Comment: cuando doy en el botón `do` no hace nada

Comment: Aparentemente no funciona en Chrome, pero sí que funciona en IE :O

Comment: A mí tampoco me funciona en Chrome v56 pero si me funciona en IE v11. El fiddle está "raro". Haz puesto todo el código en la sección HTML, se supone que el estándar de la industria es separar el HTML, JavaScript y CSS, por eso JsFiddle tiene un panel para cada uno. Por otro lado, ¿por qué no usaste el equivalente a JsFiddle de SOes?

Comment: Quise decir que también me parece "raro" que hayas usasdo JsFiddle en lugar de su equivalente en SOes

Comment: @Rubén no sabía que podía poner ese código en la propia página :O no tengo práctica con los snippets.

Comment: Pues entonces mi aporte resultó tener algo de valor, jeje

Comment: @Rubén todo el *apegotamiento* del códgio en el HTML se debe a dos razones: la primera y más vergonzante es mi falta de experiencia en esta tecnología; la segunda es que pensé en hacer un ejemplo lo más simple posible (el código real tiene muchas más líneas) pensé, tal vez de manera errónea, que poner todo en el mismo sitio sería lo más sencillo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53373/discussion-between-ruben-and-paperbirdmaster).

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta parcial y corta

Usa https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ para experimentar con los estilos o bien consulta [la documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference)

## Crítica de la pregunta

Me parece que

1. la publicación es demasiado amplia ya que incluye varias preguntas
2. el código incluido como ejemplo puede minimizarse así como mejorar su facilidad de lectura y documentación en línea
3. el código no se ha separado apropiadamente (separación de intereses / "separation of concerns")

A continuación se muestra un ejemplo de código mínimo completo y verificable que genera un mapa de la ciudad de Barcelona sin modificar los estilos, y a su lado, un mapa con los estilos modificados, usando la herramienta incluida "fragmento HTML/JavaScript/CSS. La documentación en línea se muestra al mínimo.

Nótese que el código HTML y JavaScript estan en páneles diferentes y que funciona en Chrome

```js
//URL del mapa estático sin estilos
function create_url1(lat, lng, zoom)
{
  var head = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lng;
  var zoom = "&zoom=" + zoom;
  var tail = "&size=400x400";
  return head + zoom + tail;
}
//URL del mapa estático con estilos
function create_url2(lat, lng, zoom)
{
  var head = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lng;
  var zoom = "&zoom=" + zoom;
  var tail = 
      "&size=400x400" +
      "&style=element:labels|visibility:off" +
      "&style=feature:road|color:0xffffff" +
      "&style=feature:landscape|color:0x000000" +
      "&style=feature:poi.park|color:0x00ff00" +
      "&style=feature:water|color:0x0000ff";
  return head + zoom + tail;
}
//Datos de Barcelona (location)
var lat = 41.3850639;
var lng = 2.1734035;
//Zoom
var zoom = 17;
//Llamar a las funciones que generan los urls con y sin estilos
document.getElementById("map_img1").src = create_url1(lat, lng, zoom);
document.getElementById("map_img2").src = create_url2(lat, lng, zoom);
```

```html
<img id="map_img1" src="" width="300" height="300"/>
<img id="map_img2" src="" width="300" height="300"/>
```